# titlefont, chapter, section

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titles, titlesec

I am struggling to get chapter section like the picture below.

So far i have got this which basically not produce the sectioning i want

[image]

My code is as;

```
\usepackage{titlesec,geometry,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
%Chapter Headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\adjustbox{lap=.7\width}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{7cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: The code i have, do not produce the attached picture

Comment: As far as I understand, the picture is the wanted and the code just a MWE...

Comment: Exactly - hope you can help

Comment: @YunusSalih ... Please consider accepting some of the answers given to you (if they solve the problem) in order to make them useful to future visitors/users. Leaving a question without an accepted answer makes the question less valuable in such sites/forums.

Comment: sorry for that  - fas

Comment: Don't be sorry ... Just do it in the future and past posts in order to make the answers/questions usefull to others before they have to check themselves... (really nice that you accepted the easier -and such the best- solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}


\usepackage{titlesec,geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge}
  {\filleft\textsc{\large\chaptertitlename}%
      \makebox[0pt]{\hspace{2em}\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\thechapter}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule \vspace{1ex}%
      \filleft\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks it works - I usually use report as documentclass, does it change too much on the layout ?

Comment: @YunusSalih Shouldn't make a difference, but just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

With some tikz help for the overlay:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,geometry,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\chaptikzmark}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (Chap\arabic{mychapter});\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcommand\AddNumber{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,baseline=0] \node[shift={(6mm,0.55cm)}] at (Chap\arabic{mychapter}) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\bfseries\arabic{chapter}}};\end{tikzpicture}}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
%Chapter Headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \refstepcounter{mychapter}\chaptikzmark}
  {10pt}{\raggedleft\rule{\textwidth}{0.35mm}\linebreak\huge\bfseries\AddNumber}



\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
  }
  {10pt}{\raggedleft\rule{\textwidth}{0.35mm}\linebreak\huge\bfseries}  

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter*{Test}
\chapter{A new chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks man - it helped alot

Comment: Welcome! Happy TeXing!